# Sumar el valor de una lista de diccionarios con la misma clave

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo una lista de diccionarios

```
lst = [ {'x': 1, 'y': 2}, {'x': 1, 'y': 3 }, {'x': 2, 'y': 2 } ]
```

Los diccionarios siempre tienen las mismas claves y son los valores los que cambian en todo momento.

Entonces me gustaría sumar el valor de las clave "y" cuando la clave "x" tiene el mismo valor.

El output tendría que dar : `lst # [{'x': 1, 'y': 5 }, {'x': 2, 'y': 2 }].`

Comment: Hola Yoel. Debes siempre agregar que has intentado para resolver el problema. Una aclaración, ¿con lo de "la misma clave" quieres decir "sumar el valor de la clave 'y' de los diccionarios que tienen el **mismo valor** en la clave 'x'"?  ¿ **Todos** los diccionarios de la lista van a tener **siempre** las mismas claves? ¿Son siempre "x" e "y" o es solo un ejemplo para representar el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es usar `itertools.groupby` para agrupar los diccionarios según el valor de la clave `'x'`. Hecho esto es simple usar compresión de listas para obtener la lista final, sumando los valores de la clave `'y'` (y también otras claves si existieran):

```
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter



lst = [{'x': 1, 'y': 2}, {'x': 1, 'y': 3 }, {'x': 2, 'y': 2 }]

grupos = itertools.groupby(sorted(lst, key=itemgetter('x')), key=itemgetter('x'))

res = [{'x': v, 'y': sum(dicc['y'] for dicc in diccs)} for v, diccs in grupos]

print(res)
```

La salida es `[{'x': 1, 'y': 5}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Otra solución alternativa:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [{'x': 1, 'y': 2}, {'x': 1, 'y': 3 }, {'x': 2, 'y': 2 }]

aux = defaultdict(int)
for d in lst:
    aux[d['x']] += d['y']

res = [{'x':k, 'y':v} for (k,v) in res.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado el problema, tal que así.

```
lst = [ {'x': 1, 'y': 2}, {'x': 1, 'y': 3 }, {'x': 2, 'y': 2 } ]

result_list = []
name_dict = {}
for dict_item in lst:
    x = dict_item['x']
    y = dict_item['y']
    if x in name_dict:
        pos = name_dict[x]
        result_list[pos] = {'x':x, 'y': (result_list[pos]['y']+y)}
    else:
        result_list.append(dict_item)
        name_dict[x] = len(result_list) - 1

print result_list
```